# Find JSON object based on variable NextJS

Tags: next.js

I'm trying my hand at NextJS with dynamic routing, and I'm trying to figure out how to get one specific JSON object, based on a variable.

I have the variable available (I checked with a `console.log`), but I can't figure out how to do a `find` or maybe a `where` search in the `json`?

My JSON-objects look like this:

```
0 {
 client_id: 382
 event_no: 92503
 event_name: "Sommerbuffet"
 event_notes: ""
 event_waitlist_enabled: 0
 is_product: 1
 event_season_id: 6724409054033
 event_season_name: "Sæson 2021"
 event_excluded: 0
 sales_period: {…}
 sales_stop: {…}
 event_link: "URL"
 event_images: {…}
 shows: […]
}
```

The variable I have available is `event_no`, so I'm trying to figure out how to find the object that fits with `event_no`

```
export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const event_no = context.params.event_no
  // Adding console.log(event_no) here, outputs the correct number
  const res = await fetch(
    'URL_TO_JSON'
  )
  const data = await res.json()

  return {
    props: { event: data },
  }
}
```

And here is where I'm trying to use it, but where nothing is output:

```
export default function Details({ event }) {
  console.log(event)
  return (
    <Box padding='lg'>
      <h1>{event?.event_name}</h1>
      <Card padding='md'>
        <Stack gap='sm'>
          <Text>{event?.event_notes}</Text>
          <Text>
            {event?.sales_period?.start_time} - {event?.sales_period?.end_time}
          </Text>
          <a
            className='buy-btn btn basm basm_select main-buy-btn solid'
            data-event_no={event?.event_no}
          >
            Køb
          </a>
        </Stack>
      </Card>
    </Box>
  )
}
```

I feel like I'm very close, and that it's just the final nudge I'm missing, which I hope someone here can give!
The page is loading, so the routing is working, and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong in the way I fetch the data, however, I just can't find out how to prepare and then output the data properly.

Comment: Just to confirm, is the prop `event` and array of objects or a single object?

Comment: I'm sorry, the whole lingo hasn't set yet for me, so I don't know if I'm answering you correctly, but the JSON I posted is one `event`, so it has all the stuff like `client_id`, `event_no` etc. inside of it. So I'd say it's an array of objects?

Comment: If the `events` are an array, then you can use `.map()` to iterate through the items and render them. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: I have a front page where I map the original file and list all `events`. I am now trying to make this dynamic routing work, where I want to only render the content of the JSON-object that has the same `event_no` as the `event_no` I have in a variable.

Comment: `props: { event: data.find(el => el.event_no === event_no) }` should do the work here

Comment: just check if you find it before sending it

Comment: Yep, what @NicolasMenettrier said.

Comment: @NicolasMenettrier Yep, that seems to do the trick partially! now, `event?.event_name` just outputs the very first object's `event_name` though, and not the `event_name` that actually fits with `event_no`?

Comment: Aha! The triple `=` broke it, double `=` works and single `=` returns the wrong info!